# Best Way to Remove Last Character in Each Line of a File

Tags: java, regex, file

I have a file that has a extra caret at the end of each line that I need to delete. What would be the best way about doing this? Is is always the 6th caret in the line that needs to be deleted.

I have thought about using a scanner to run through each character, then increment a variable every time a ^ is hit. From here, if the variable had a remainder of 0 after being divided by 6, I would write a space instead of the ^. I would just create a new file to write to, while having the original file be a temp file. Would this would well or is there a better way to go about this?

I believe I could possibly also use a caret as a delimiter and stay with the incrementing strategy to determine when to write a caret.

I would prefer to write a method in Java to take care of this, as the program which writes the original file is through a method in a java program

I have shown below what each line of the file would look like.

```
02/03/2014^CV-13-798497^10/31/2013^N/A^SH^CUYAHOGA COUNTY SHERIFF DEPT  SERVICE FEE $43.00^
02/03/2014^CV-13-798497^10/31/2013^N/A^CS^NO SALE FORECLOSURE CLERK FEE -  $5.00^
02/03/2014^CV-13-798497^10/22/2013^P1^CS^FORECLOSURE PAGE COUNT^
```

Comment: The title says "remove last character", but in the question you mention the 6th caret. Which is it? What tools can you use? sed, any particular editor?

Comment: What are the parameters to your question? Does this need to be a script (Windows or Linux) or is this something that you are interested in uploading into a program to have done?

Comment: regex would just simply be: `\^$`

Comment: I would prefer to it in a method in java, as the program which gives the original file is written in Java. Sorry for not specifying earlier. @Bugs it is the last character in every line, which is also the 6th caret on every line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java solution:

```
// read file data into a String
String data = new Scanner(new File("file.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
// replace all ^ from end of line using (?m) - MULTILINE switch
data = data.replaceAll("(?m)\\^$", "");
```

Comment: Works Great! How does that work to delete only the last caret on each line?

Comment: That is because of `\\^$` which finds `^` only at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with `sed`:

```
sed 's/\^$//' inputfile > outputfile
```